# django No Reverse Match from different model

Tags: django

I am working on a project when something spit the following error:

```
Reverse for 'project-file-delete' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['projects/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/project\\-file/delete/$']
```

here is my main urlpattern:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', welcome_view.home, name='welcome'),
    path('projects/', include('projects.urls'))]
```

my project app's urlpattern:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', ProjectListView.as_view(), name='project-home'),
    path('user_project/<str:username>/', UserProjectListView.as_view(), name='user-projects'),
    path('<int:pk>/', ProjectDetailView.as_view(), name='project-detail'),
    path('new/', ProjectCreateView.as_view(), name='project-create'),
    path('<int:pk>/update/', ProjectUpdateView.as_view(), name='project-update'),
    path('<int:pk>/delete/', ProjectDeleteView.as_view(), name='project-delete'),
    path('<int:pk>/create_base_file/', ProjectFileCreateView.as_view(), name='project-base-file'),
    path('<int:pk>/project-file/delete/', ProjectFileDeleteView.as_view(), name='project-file-delete'),
    path('<int:pk>/project_file/', views.proj_file_detail, name='project-file-detail'),
]
```

my project's model class definition:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('project-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class ProjectFile(models.Model):
    FILE_TYPE = (
        ('base', 'Base File'),
        ('transformed', 'Transformed File'),
        ('discretized', 'Discretized File'),
        ('model', 'Model File')
    )

    file = models.FileField(upload_to='project-files', default=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = 'base', choices = FILE_TYPE)
    description = models.TextField(default = 'base file')
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('project-detail', kwargs = {'pk': self.project}) #kwargs={ 'project': self.project })
```

The template where the error is raised:

```
{% block page_heading %}
<div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-4">
    <h1 class="h3 mb-0 text-gray-800">Project's Detail</h1>
</div>
{% endblock page_heading %}

{% block content %}

<div class="jumbotron col-xl-10 col-md-6 mb-1">
    <h5>{{ object.name }}  </h5>
    <img class="img-profile rounded-circle" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}">
    <p> {{ object.author }}</p>        
    <p> {{ object.date_created|date:"F d, Y" }}</p>
    <p> {{ object.description }}</p>
    <p> Project File(s):</p>

        <table class="table table-hover table-default">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Filename</th>
                    <th scope="col">Classification</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                {% for file in project_files %}
                    <tr class="table-default">
                        {% if object.author == user %}
                            <th scope="row"><a href="{% url 'project-file-detail' object.id %}">{{ file.file }} </a></th>
                        {% else %}
                            <th scope="row">{{ file.file }}</th> 
                        {% endif %}
                        <td>{{ file.category }}</td>

                        <td>
                            <a class="float-sm-right" href="{% url 'project-file-delete' object.id %}">
                                Describe File
                            </a>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <a class="float-sm-right" href="{% url 'project-file-delete' object.ProjectFile %}">
                                <i class="fas fa-fw fa-trash" style="font-size:16px;color:red"></i>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>


    {% if object.author == user %}
        <a class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'project-base-file' object.id %}">NEXT | Upload Base File</a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'project-update' object.id %}">Update</a>
        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1 float-sm-right" href="{% url 'project-delete' object.id %}">Delete this project</a>
    {% endif%}
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

The Project's Detail view that causes the error:

```
class ProjectDetailView(DetailView):
model = Project
context_object_name = 'projects'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    file = ProjectFile.objects.filter(project=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
    # file = file
    context["project_files"] = file

    return context
```

and finally my Project File Delete View:

```
class ProjectFileDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'projects/project_file_confirm_delete.html'   # template for deletion
    success_url ='/projects/'                                     # url after successfull deletion

    # Test user permission
    def test_func(self):                            
        project = self.get_object()

        if self.request.user == project.author:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: You haven't shown the relevant code. Where is the template that that error happens on, and where is the view that generate it? We need the thing that is generating the link, not the place it is supposed to link to.

Comment: I edited the post and reflected the template and the view...

Comment: Do you want to delete a project or a file in a particular project?\

Comment: No I just want to display the project detail. But when the DetailView is called this Reverse error is raised.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I have included the files. What do you think is the cause of the error? Please help...

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be like this?

```
<a class="float-sm-right" 
   href="{% url 'project-file-delete' file.file.id %}">
    Describe File
</a>
```

**Edit**

I think, you are getting confused with the variable names that you have used. It'd be better to change the code to something given below.

*view*

```
project_files = ProjectFile.objects.filter(project=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
context["project_files"] = project_files
```

*template*

```
{% for project_file in project_files %}
...
<th scope="row">{{ project_file.file }}</th>
...
<a class="float-sm-right" 
       href="{% url 'project-file-delete' project_file.id %}">
...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I think you've got a duplicate `file`; it should be `{% url 'project-file-delete' project_file.id %}`.

Comment: This is causing the error `<a class="float-sm-right" href="{% url 'project-file-delete' object.projectfile.id %}">
                                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-trash" style="font-size:16px;color:red"></i>
                                </a>`  

Changing 
`href="{% url 'project-file-delete' object.projectfile.id %}` 
to 
`href="{% url 'project-file-delete' project_file.id %}`

Solves the problem. Thanks @DanielRoseman